# bitcoinlib.wallets.WalletError: Not enough unspent transaction outputs found

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoinlib

I'm coding in python and I want to send funds from my wallet in bitcoinlib.wallets to another wallet. I have  0.00017984 bitcoin in my wallet and everytime I try to send bitcoin to my exodus wallet it says:

bitcoinlib.wallets.WalletError: Not enough unspent transaction outputs found

I don't know what the error is. My code so far is:

```
from bitcoinlib.wallets import Wallet
import time
import threading

w = Wallet('Wallet1')

t = w.send_to('bc1qtrflvfw99jzqakvxt985d7jls6tm8mwtxjr652', ' 0.00017984 BTC', offline=False)
```

Can someone show me how to send bitcoin from one wallet to another properly?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are creating your wallet correctly. You did `w = Wallet('Wallet1')`, do this instead `w = Wallet.create('Wallet1')`. Visit https://pypi.org/project/bitcoinlib/#description for more information.